# image 404 error (via JSON:API)

Tags: 8

My 'gatsby develop' command fails as image files (coming from Drupal 8) are returning a 404 error - I don't understand why (this is new)

== Details: ==

JSON:API (which Gatsby uses to build the site), uses this URL:
https://dev-tuckel.pantheonsite.io/jsonapi/file/file

it provides this image URL:

https://dev-tuckel.pantheonsite.io/sites/default/files/2020-08/mckenzie%20falls.jpg

Which returns a 404. There are at least 3 other images that are returning a 404 error - this is strange.

== Investigation: ==

In: content> Files:
the file is 165.17 KB, which is strange, as I ussually upload higher quality images.

it also says it has 1 "use count", however the "entity" field is empty (again, not usual)

I cleared the Admin > Performance cache (thinking it's may a thumbnail / cache file error).

The site is hosted in the free dev tier of pantheon.

Prior: I was not working on Drupal at the time of failure, I was working on Gatsby code.

If you have any ideas, it would really help because I'm stumped.

Comment: Where are the correct files?  SFTP into the files directory and find them to check what is going on.

Comment: thanks, I got in via an SFTP client, folder the folders they belong to and the files to do not exist. More info: I'm not familiar with these files, I don't believe I have uploaded them.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to delete the files via JSON:API (thank god that exists) using Postman.

The FIDs were: 1,2,8,9 - indicating that the files were very early on in the development of the site. I think they may have belonged to article content types that were recently removed (and therefor orphaned) - however I was still able to build the gatsby sites after this.

However, I think it was straight after I deleted the .cache folder from the Gatsby build that I had this issue, so it's possible that I had the images cached, they were then orphaned (during deletion of the 'article' content type.). Although I would have expected that Drupal would have done appropriate deletion of files and records when removing a content type.

Comment: can you tell me how you deleted the files, i am facing the same issue